# Move From SpriteKit scene to SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to move back to a SwiftUI view from a SpriteKit Scene. I currently have a Swift UI "main menu" which looks like this.

```
struct MainMenu: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                Text("Replicator")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding()
                
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "play.circle")
                            .font(.title3)
                        
                        Text("Start")
                            .font(.title)
                        
                    }
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 50)
                    .background(.cyan)
                    .cornerRadius(25)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ContentView() is what contains the SpriteKit game and that looks like the following.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var scene: SKScene {
        
        let scene = Level_1()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 750, height: 1334)
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        return scene
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        
        VStack {
            
            SpriteView(scene: scene)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
           
            
        }
    }
}
```

My question is... once I'm in ContentView how do I return to "Main Menu"?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode`

So you can create a button and call

```
presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

Or you can pass a binding var to Content View and set to false like so:

In MainMenu

```
struct MainMenu: View {
    @State var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {             
                Text("Replicator")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding()
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(isPresented: $isPresented).navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true), isActive: $isPresented) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "play.circle")
                            .font(.title3)
                        Text("Start")
                            .font(.title)
                    
                    }
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 50)
                    .background(.cyan)
                    .cornerRadius(25)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var scene: SKScene {
    let scene = Level_1()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 750, height: 1334)
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        return scene
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {            
            SpriteView(scene: scene)
                .ignoresSafeArea() 
            Button(action: { //You can put the button wherever you want as long as you pass in the isPresented Binding
                isPresented.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Back to MainMenu")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it's got me moving in the right direction again. :)